# Coalesce/IsNull functionality in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

How can I make a property in a class return a certain string if its a certain condition eg/empty

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  publc string MiddleName{get;set;}
  public string Surname{get;set;}
  public string Gender{get;set;}
}

List<Person> people = repo.GetPeople();
List<Person> formatted = people.GroupBy(x=>x.Gender).//?? format Gender to be a certain string eg/"Not Defined" if blank
```

Comment: Might not be applicable, but i'd have an enum for gender as there are only so many options.

Comment: You're correct but this is just an example not my real code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
people.GroupBy(x=>x.Gender ?? "Not Available").ToList();
```

Update: (to catch empty strings)

```
people.GroupBy(x=> String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Gender) ? "None" : x.Gender).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If this was a local situation, i would fix the null with ?? at the place it's needed.

If a more generic solution is needed, which I recommend. I was go for fix it directly in the getter (or setter, if desired).

```
 private string _gender;
 public string Gender
 {
    get {
        string val = 
           (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_gender) ? _gender : "[Not decided yet]");
        return val; 
    }
    set { _gender = value; }
 }
```

And within a test sample program in it's whole,

```
public class Nullable
{
    public class Person
    {
      private string _gender;
      public string Gender
      {
          get {
              string val = 
                 (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_gender) ? _gender : "[Not decided yet]");
              return val; 
          }
          set { _gender = value; }
      }

      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string MiddleName { get; set; }
      public string Surname { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        List<Person> p = new List<Person>();
        p.Add(new Person() { Name = "John Doe", Gender = "Male" });
        p.Add(new Person() { Name = "Jane Doe", Gender = "Female" });
        p.Add(new Person() { Name = "Donna Doe", Gender = "Female" });
        p.Add(new Person() { Name = "UnDoe",  });

        // test 1
        foreach (var item in p.GroupBy(x => x.Gender))
            Console.WriteLine(item.Count() + " " + item.Key);

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

        //test 2
        foreach (var item in p)
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name + "\t" + item.Gender);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (I'm using an int for the property type):

```
public class Widget
{
  private int? MyPropertyBackingStore ;
  public int MyProperty
  {
    get
    {
      int value = 0 ; // the default value
      if ( this.MyPropertyBackingStore.HasValue && this.MyPropertyBackingStore > 0 )
      {
        value = this.MyPropertyBackingStore.Value ;
      }
      return value ;
    }
    set
    {
      this.MyPropertyBackingStore = value ;
    }
  }
}
```

Or, since it's a property so it's trivial to control how/what values get set: simply tweak the property value in the settor.

```
public class Widget
{
  private int MyPropertyBackingStore ;
  public int MyProperty
  {
    get
    {
      return this.MyPropertyBackingStore ;
    }
    set
    {
      if ( this.MyPropertyBackingStore.HasValue && this.MyPropertyBackingStore > 0 )
      {
        this.MyPropertyBackingStore = value ;
      }
      else
      {
        this.MyPropertyBackingStore = -1 ;
      }
    }
  }
}
```